# Find an object and its properties within a larger object with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
family = {
  'person1':[{"id":"1111","name":"adam", "sex":"male", "born":"USA"}],
  'person2':[{"id":"2222","name":"sarah", "sex":"female", "born":"Canada"}],
  'person3':[{"id":"3333","name":"adam", "sex":"male", "born":"USA"}]
};
```

Given the family object above, how do I extract all the properties (id, name, sex, born) of one of the person objects that have a specific id (or name) value? eg id=1111

So ideally I can get a new object personInQuestion that I can manipulate, where:

```
personInQuestion = {"id":"1111","name":"adam", "sex":"male", "born":"USA"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the object, and grab the element that matches.

```
var search = 1111;

var personInQuestion = {};
for(var x in family){
    var item = family[x][0];
    if(item.id == search){
        personInQuestion = item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think jQuery is the best tool for this, instead I suggest you taking a look [at the Where method that the Backbone library offers](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where). Not sure if it would be overkill.

Usage is like this:

```
var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

var musketeers = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});

alert(musketeers.length);
```

Comment: I would say that integrating Backbone for this would probably be overkill since Backbone is more of a framework. Using a more utility-oriented library like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not provide selectors for JSON (JavaScript Object) data, so you would need to iterate over the object. For example:

```
result =  null;
$.each(family, function(i, v) {
  if (v.id === "1111" && v.name === "adam" ...) {
    result = v;
    return;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of Rob Hruska's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634887/find-an-object-and-its-properties-within-a-larger-object-with-javascript-jquery#comment15410388_11634993)(in a comment) to use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

```
family = {
  'person1':[{"id":"1111","name":"adam", "sex":"male", "born":"USA"}],
  'person2':[{"id":"2222","name":"sarah", "sex":"female", "born":"Canada"}],
  'person3':[{"id":"3333","name":"adam", "sex":"male", "born":"USA"}]
};

var searchId = 1111;

var person = _.find(family, function(item) { return item[0].id == searchId; })[0];
```